# NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Nom de répertoire non valide:

Tags: python

I want to train my model, but when I execute the code I have notAdirectoryError. I verified the path of my directory and it seems true. Here is my code, the code reads just the first image in the directory and stop.

```
import os
import cv2
import mahotas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import joblib
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import h5py
train_path = r'C:\Users\yousr\Desktop\prjNew\train\fusible40'
test_path= r'C:\Users\yousr\Desktop\prjNew\test'
def extractFeatures(train_path):
 # liste les dossier existe ds path train
   global_Features =[]
   global_Labels=[]
   train_labels = os.listdir(train_path)
 #print(train_labels)
   for l in train_labels:
     dir = os.path.join(train_path, l)
     print(dir)
     imgs = os.listdir(dir)
     #print(imgs)
     for img in imgs:
         file =os.path.join(dir,img)
         print(file)
         image = cv2.imread(file)
         global_Features.append(getFeatures(image))
         global_Labels.append(l)
         
    with h5py.File('features.h5','w') as h5f:
       h5f.create_dataset("features", data=np.asarray(global_Features) )
         
    with h5py.File('labels.h5','w') as h5f:
    h  5f.create_dataset("labels", data=np.asarray(global_Labels) )

    return global_Features,global_Labels
def main():
   x_train, y_train = extractFeatures(train_path)
   x_test, y_test = extractFeatures(test_path)
   svc=trainingSVC(x_train, y_train)
    
   y_predict=svc.predict(x_test)
   print("SVM accueacy : ",accuracy_score(y_test,y_predict))
   #testing(test_path)

  #    plot(images, test_path)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please edit your question to make the code a valid python code? I see some indentation errors for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you doubled `\\` in your path?

**To give an example:**

```
D:\\......
```

It looks like this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```py
train_path = r'C:\Users\yousr\Desktop\prjNew\train\fusible40'
```

Is not a valid path. You need to escape the `\` character.
Either use `C:\\Users\\yousr\\Desktop\\prjNew\\train\\fusible40`
or

```py
train_path = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\yousr\Desktop\prjNew\train\fusible40')
```